# How to download Assets files as ZIP

Tags: assets

I could really use some help here. Might have promised something that cannot be done.

I am creating a simple doc repository for a client. The idea is for each of their "jobs", they create a unique asset folder. They upload a bunch of assets to it and then create a "review" entry that shows particular assets to be reviewed by their client. Sometimes these are html emails, or banner images, or even videos they create.

Anyway, each asset needs a "view" link {url} and then a "download link". The download is always a zip file which might contain more files than just the {url} file. My current code is:

```
{asset_files}
<h2 class="tableHeads">{title}</h2>
<p class="tablecity">
{if desc}{desc}<br />{/if}
<a href="{url}" target="_blank">view</a> | <a href="{url}">download</a>
</p>
{/asset_files}
```

How would you go about making the download link point to the zip asset without actually making a new entire asset entry out of it?

I am at a loss here and could really use some ideas.

Thanks

Mike

Hi again,

I changed the links to:

```
<a href="{url}" target="_blank">view</a> | <a href="{url}.zip">download</a>
```

But this requires the zip file be named exactly the same as the asset and also, I am not including the zip files in the entry itself. It works but is really funky and not really an ideal solution.

Comment: For me it's unclear how the name of the zip-archive is generated if it is not the same as {url}.zip.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at either [MX Zip](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mx-zip), or to get more advanced, [Link Vault](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/link-vault) and [Link Vault Zipper](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/link-vault-zipper). These add-ons create ZIP files on the fly for you from a list of file URLs you feed to them.